An integral of a trigonometric function
I am asked to show
$$ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1-\cos 2\pi (m+1)\theta}{1-\cos 2\pi \theta} \mathrm{d}\theta = m+1$$
where $m\geqslant 0$. (I believe it is a classical result, so if it is asked somewhere please point it out, thanks.)
My idea is to calculate the integrand using duplication formulas. I find that in case of $m=0,1,2$, $\frac{1-\cos 2\pi (m+1)\theta}{1-\cos 2\pi \theta}$ reduces to a polynomial of $\cos 2\pi \theta$ with constant term $m+1$, which proves the result.
Can we show the similar thing for general $m$? I cannot see how. Or are there any other ways to prove it? (Maybe related to complex analysis?)
Thanks in advance.

Substitute $x= 2 \pi \theta$ and then use  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173370/42969

@MartinR  Thank you!
